# Poll data from remote database and create a notification to the user

Tags: android

Quite a while now, I have been using GCM to sending push messages to my android app users. Now I want to be able to poll data from my remote database to the app users when remote database receives new insertion. I want to create a notification when there is a new insertion into the remote database.

I understand I would have to create background services which is set to every second check from the remote database, this has  set backs as the battery life of the user would be highly affected.

Again, I learnt about alarm manager which also sets to a period of time to poll data from the database.

Now I want to understand the better way to poll data from remote database and creating a notification to the user even when the app is inactive or in the background.

Answer (score 0):

There is, you can make the server send a notification to the devices when new data has been added. This can be done with server code or if you don't want to do all the data base code there are applications that you can use. If you have your own server you can use parse.com since they are taking their hosting services down January 2017. If you don't have you can use Firebase and Batch to get the job done.